# IntelliJ git commit message template

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there any way to set default Git commit message or commit message template in IntelliJ? 
For example I would like that every commit message will look like:

1. Commit subject:
2. Feature:
3. Reviewer:

Comment: Not an answer, but as an alternative you could consider having a hook on the server that enforces "correct" commit messages. See e.g. http://addamhardy.com/blog/2013/06/05/good-commit-messages-and-enforcing-them-with-git-hooks/

Comment: Also, the "reviewer" is probably better stored in a "git note" - usually you want to commit first, and then review.

Comment: Not sure whether this applicable with intellij: `The prepare-commit-msg hook is run before the commit message editor is fired up but after the default message is created. It lets you edit the default message before the commit author sees it.` from http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: the issue with the suggested solution using git hook is that every developer will have to install the hook. I'm looking for something much simpler (I did it before with Eclipse and SVN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now all JetBrains products have this feature from 2021.1 release out of the box.

More details: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2021-1/#page__content-version-control

Comment: Where exactly are more details about templating commit? Please expand you answer and at least say where is the in-built setting or something.

Comment: The correct link is here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2021-1/#version-control and there is only this paragraph:

"Support for Git commit templates
IntelliJ IDEA supports Git commit templates. If you want to create a custom commit message, you can use a template and fill it in with the information you feel is important. The IDE will then display this text as an initial commit message."
So the actually just added support for `git commit.template` config https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/2.10.5#Documentation/git-commit.txt---templateltfilegt

Answer (score 7):

Try the [Commit Message Template](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9364-commit-message-template) plugin.

After you install it, follow the instructions:

> Set a template: Open Settings > Tools > Commit Message Template and
> enter the desired template or set the path to a template file.
>
> If you set something in the comment characters, any line in the
> template file that starts with that character will be ignored when
> building the message

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you the Plugin "Git Commit Message Plugin":

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10100-git-commit-message-plugin

it's easy to use and allows templates to autofill from your branchname (like a ticket id or name):

The template description:

> "The following template placeholders are supported: ${ticket} - The
> ticketId (default: Git Branch Name). ${shortDescription} - Title or
> short commit description. ${longDescription} - A detailed commit
> description."

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own template file.

Assuming your template is under `~/.gitmessage` you can run:

`git config --local commit.template ~/.gitmessage`

`--local` is important, if you set `--global` it won't work.